# Using a Boost library in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: winforms, boost, c++-cli

I have issues when trying to compile Boost in a Windows Forms application.

I was told it is because I must compile using `/clr` in order to use Boost, and Windows Forms applications default to `/clr:pure`.

Is there anyway to get around this issue so that I can use the Boost library?

Comment: Well that would be nice and all, except that you can't compile a winform app as a /clr, but if you try, you'll get about 3000000 compile errors + a popup window with an error message.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason that a WinForms app needs to be compiled with `/clr:pure`. It works just fine with `/clr`. Not sure what those errors you're getting are; your code is probably invalid or some other compiler setting is incorrect.